# Two windows - Mono

Tags: window, mono

I want to open 2 projects of mono at the same time(working at the same time too), but when i open mono, the first window will always be opened. What can I do?

Comment: Which application are you using to open them?

Answer (score 1):

Opening Multiple Solutions in MONO

MonoDevelop now supports opening multiple solutions at the same time. This is useful when you are working with a solution and want to review code side-by-side which belongs to another solution. To open a solution without closing the currently opened, you can:

Click on the Open command, select the solution, and uncheck the "Close current workspace" option.
In the "Recent Solutions" menu, click on the solution you want to open while holding the Control key. The same applies when opening from the Welcome Page.